# How can I make docker-compose pull images using a socks5 proxy?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, socks

I use `port-forwarding` like this:

```
ssh -vND 1080 user@server_ip
```

**Question:**

How can I pull docker images with `socks5`?

> pulling docker images with the `docker pull` command already has an answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/739504/how-can-i-make-docker-compose-pull-images-using-a-socks5-proxy).
> But I want to use `docker-compose` for pulling images

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the proxy config in the services [systemd](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy) config (`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`):

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
```

[image: docker pull socks proxy]

The service config works for `docker-compose pull` as well:
[image: docker-compose pull socks proxy]

Answer (score 2):

If your service is maintained by `systemd`,set `http proxy` and `https proxy` in the service config file,`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf`:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=socks5://<proxy host>:<port>"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://<proxy host>:<port>"
```

Then,restart docker service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to edit the docker config file `~/.docker/config.json` and add the following entry in the json file.

```
"proxies": {
   "default": {
     "httpProxy": "socks5://127.0.0.1:1080",
     "httpsProxy": "socks5://127.0.0.1:1080",
     "noProxy": "127.0.0.0/8"
   }
}
```

In my case the proxy was on localhost port 1080, but this can be changed to any other proxy address.